# Can I go to Paris with same visa used for my trip to Greece?

Tags: visas, multiple-entry, schengen-visas

I have a multiple entry Greece visa valid for 90 days. After going to Greece and returning home to India, can I go to Paris a month later using the same visa issued by Greece? The Paris trip would be for a week or so. Will it be possible or will there be any problems?

Comment: Sorry to close your first question as a duplicate.  If you still have a question after reviewing that one, please respond here with a comment, and edit your question to clarify, and I will reopen it.